# Magento 2 Autoload error

Tags: magento2.2.2, varien-autoload

I am using Magento 2.2.2 version.

I have configured the setup in my local and it is working fine.

When I moved to the server, it is not working.

I am getting the following error.

I have followed the below steps:

1. Gave 777 to the entire folder.

I have got the below error:

`Autoload error
Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.`

**Update**:

I am trying to install composer using the command `composer install`.

I am getting the below output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.13.1)
Downloading: 100%
Invalid zip file, retrying...
```

It is downloading the files and says `Invalid zip file, retrying...` so many times.

Comment: please mention the error you are facing in Magento on your live server

Comment: are you using shared hosting ?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI I have mentioned the error in the point 2.

Comment: Did you installed the magento first on your server? or you directly migrated your localhost's magento to your server?

Comment: Did you manually move the instance or are you using git?

Comment: How you move site from local to server ?

Comment: giving 777 for entire folder is not recommended. Please clear cache folder, generation, view_preprocessd etc from var, redeploy, give permission and see. it should fix.

Comment: @VivekKumar I am cloning files from git.

Comment: My server is not shared hosting.

Comment: @Sarvanan  Please run 'composer install' under application root directory. https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Vendor-autoload-is-not-found-Please-run-composer-install-under/m-p/82770#M3391

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan I have checked the composer.json file. It has the url  `https://repo.magento.com/` only.

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced same issue few days ago. What i just did was i went to
**app/etc/env.php** and changed the **hostname** from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1**, and it worked for me. I hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: In local it is working fine. I am getting the error on the server only. I didn't get the initial setup wizard too.

Comment: @SaravananDS are you using shared hosting ?

Comment: @KishanPatadia It is not shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> I am cloning files from git.

I would like to point out that most of the time vendor folder is excluded from versioning through *.gitignore* . You should open up *.gitignore* from your root of your magento folder in your branch and you should see vendor folder along with other folders ignored , so during cloning vendor folder is not copied.

You can manually copy vendor folder or just run `composer install` if you have not modified any core files.

Comment: Yes, vendor folder is ignored. What should I do now.

Comment: The error you have reported during composer install mostly occurs due to bad network.